# MS ACCESS Report - Using CODE to change a value in a field from an OPTION Group to a different value

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

I have a report in ACCESS that Is based on a query of a table populated by a form with an Option group. ( to try to explain this better - Table is inspector qualifications, the query pulls all of the qualifications for the inspector, the qualifications are selected via option group on a form that populates the fields of the inspector qualification table.) Of course, the choices are stored as numeric values, "1, 2, 3 or 4" in the table, but 4 actually designates a N/A or NONE.  Since everything is already built out this way, I am trying to write a code that will run when the report is generated (or opened,) that will take the "4" value entered (if the field equals that) and change it to a Null value /blank in the report - not in the query or table. I still want this report to generate everything else as is - show all records - just change the value if that particular option is the one shown in that field for that particular record.
Anyone know of a good way to do this?  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!!!

Comment: Is the query for that report used anywhere else? If not, then why not change the query - that is the easiest place to do this. Otherwise, you would need to use VBA.

Comment: no, I don't believe it is.  What would be the best route to change the query?

Answer (score 0):

You would just place an 'IIF' in the query that tests for the value you want to change, then either changes it to something else, or retains the original value.  The below will test field 'Nbr1' for the presence of a 4, and if found, change it to 'N/A', otherwise it stays the same.

Note! You will need to change the control source in the report to reflect the name you provide (i.e. 'MyChange') because you can't keep the original name.

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.EMPID, Table1.TestResult, 
       IIf([Nbr1]=4,"N/A",[Nbr1]) AS MyChange, Table1.Nbr2
       FROM Table1;
```

Comment: Sorry, but where I used "N/A", I see you want empty, so just use "".

Comment: Thank you for the info - sorry to be so full of questions on this.  My original thought on this was to create an IIF statement in the query, trying to do this change.  I did not get this to work for me.  I believe this is because I may have done it in the query that pulls ALL information and not created a second query? I see above that you said "in the query that tests for the value you want to change."  should I have a query to do just that first, then pull everything needed on the report into a second query?

Comment: You said the recordsource of the report is a query. Since I have no idea what that looks like, I provided something that will work --- UNLESS you are already doing something in that query that would alter the field in question. You don't mention the name of the field or how it is derived. Can you either post your query, or else take my example, change the table and field names, and see what you get.

Comment: Wayne - thanks so much for the information - I will definitely hold onto it for future use.  In this particular case, I was having a complete brain fart - I could solve my problem simply by using conditional formatting on the cells in question.  (it was an option group that populated the cells as 1,2,3,4 for the values instead of the labels I,II,III, or none (which became 4.))  All I did was invoke conditional formatting on the cells when the value was equal to 4, it changed the text to white, making it a blank field.  This seems to work rather well.  Thanks again  for the knowledge!